# Python function that takes a positive integer n and returns the sum of the squares of all the positive integers smaller than n

Tags: python

What I think:

```
def sum_square(n):

    result = 0
    if n > 0:
        i = iter(n)
        for i in n:
            result += i * i
        return result
    elif n <= 0:
        raise ValueError("n should be positive")
print(sum_square(4))
```

However, the terminal displays that int object is not iterable. 
What's wrong with my answer? Could you do the modification based on my thought?

Comment: `for i in range(n):`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Closed form

First of all, know that the sum of squares has a [closed form](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum(n%5E2)). Here is the formula shifted to sum up to `n - 1`.

```
def sum_square(n):
    if n < 0:
        raise ValueError('n must be positive')

    return n*(n-1)*(2*n-1)//6
```

Actually, all sums of powers have [a known closed form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula#Examples).

### About your code

You cannot call `iter(n)` on an integer, you probably meant `range(n)`.

```
def sum_square(n):
    result = 0
    if n > 0:
        for i in range(n):
            result += i * i
        return result
    elif n <= 0:
        raise ValueError("n should be positive")
```

Although the above could be simplified using `sum`.

```
def sum_square(n):
    return sum(x**2 for x in range(n))
```

Comment: Worth adding that even after fixing i to be range(n), the code would break at the next line. They either want `r = range(n); for i in r:` or, much better of course, `for i in range(n):`.

Comment: @Denziloe Thanks for the remark, I updated the answer